# Loading an XML file from a specific path

Tags: python, xml

I am creating a simple GUI application to manage unknown words while learning a new language. Anyways, I am having troubles with loading an XML file from a specific path because I do not know how to properly declare filepaths. The program should first declare filepaths, check to see if the directory exists and create it if necessary, check to see whether the file (XML document) exists and create it if necessary, write start and end elements, and finally load the XML document from the specified path.

In C# and Windows, I would do it like this:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string vocabulary_path = path + "\\Vocabulary\\Words.xml";

if (!Directory.Exists(path + "\\Vocabulary"))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "\\Vocabulary");

if (!File.Exists(vocabulary_path))
{
    XmlTextWriter xW = new XmlTextWriter(vocabulary_path, Encoding.UTF8);
    xW.WriteStartElement("Words");
    xW.WriteEndElement();
    xW.Close();
}

XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(vocabulary_path);
```

...but I'm using Python and Linux Mint Xfce.

Here is what I have so far:

```
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)

my_file = Path("/path/to/file")

if not my_file.is_file():
    # create an XML document and write start and end element into it
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python use the ElementTree-Module:

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

vocabulary = os.path.join(path, "Vocabulary", "Words.xml")

if not os.path.exists(vocabulary):
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(vocabulary)):
        os.mkdirs(os.path.dirname(vocabulary))
    doc = et.Element('Words')
    tree = et.ElementTree(doc)
    tree.write(vocabulary)
else:
    tree = et.ElementTree(file=vocabulary)
```

Comment: I have edited my post, there is another issue that needs to be overcame. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @wraith1337 then you should ask a second question, not continue to add to this question.

Comment: @MatthewCole OK, sorry. I reverted the changes.

Comment: the code in this answer will fail, because `path` is undefined.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: this is a code fragment, and the OP knows how to get the `path`.

Comment: @Daniel: I don't wish to be argumentative, but this question shows that the OP does _not_ know how to set the path, or even that they need to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43379279/nameerror-name-path-is-not-defined